# Check the start value with jquery regular expressions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, regex

hello everyone I’m wondering if i can check the beginning of the value with jquery i tried this code

```
$('#ads_img').keyup(function(){

if($(this).val() ^= 'http://'){
alert('ok');
}

});
```

but it didn't work for me.

Comment: jQuery is just a DOM manipulation library. It has nothing to do with how JavaScript handles with regular expressions.

Comment: Also `^=` performs a bitwise XOR in JavaScript. Not a regex check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use regex to test the val... something like this...

```
var patt = /^http:\/\//gi;
$('#ads_img').keyup(function(){

    if(patt.exec($(this).val())){
        alert('ok');
    }

});
```

Comment: You don't need the `g` modifier, since there cannot be more than one match at the beginning of the string. And you don't need a regex for this, `indexOf()` provides the information you need and is faster. Regexes are good if you need the additional power they offer.

Answer (score 6):

try JavaScript [`indexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) Method

```
$('#ads_img').keyup(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if ( value.indexOf("http://") === 0 ) {
    alert('ok');
  }
});
```

**examples:**

```
"stackoverflow.com".indexOf("http://") // return -1, not found so false
"http://stackoverflow.com".indexOf("http://") // return 0, is at beginning so true
"sddsghttp://stackoverflow.com".indexOf("http://") // return 5, is at index 5 so false
```

Comment: I am not sure if this check at beginning

Comment: if `http://` is not at begining, then it will not return `0`, you can try with different values

Comment: You are right @Akam, it checks anywhere in the url, not the beginning.

Comment: Guys, thats why i used `0` it will return `0` if `http://` is at the beginning of the string, `-1` if it is not found in the string, please try yourself before commenting

Comment: @bystwn22 try 
"htttp://stackoverflow.com".indexOf("http://")
"https://stackoverflow.com".indexOf("http://")